# What's the default font that flex uses?

Tags: apache-flex, fonts

If I don't declare any font family in my flex application what's the default font that it uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/2/langref/flash/text/TextFormat.html), the default font is Times New Roman, or Times in Mac OS X.

Comment: the default font is verdana